# Can xargs execute a subshell command for each argument?

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a command which is attempting to generate UUIDs for files:

```
find -printf "%P\n"|sort|xargs -L 1 echo $(uuid)
```

But in the result, `xargs` is only executing the `$(uuid)` subshell once:

```
8aa9e7cc-d3b2-11e4-83a6-1ff1acc22a7e file1
8aa9e7cc-d3b2-11e4-83a6-1ff1acc22a7e file2
8aa9e7cc-d3b2-11e4-83a6-1ff1acc22a7e file3
```

Is there a one-liner (i.e not a function) to get `xargs` to execute a subshell command on each input?

Comment: @TomFenech: `-n 1` would actually split by any whitespace, whether line-interior or not, so the command would break with paths with embedded whitespace;  `-L 1` comes closer to the intent, in that it performs line-by-line processing, but word-splitting is still applied to each line, so that potentially _multiple_ arguments are passed to `echo` per input line (which may or may not cause problems). The robust approach is to use `-I`, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because the `$(uuid)` gets expanded in the current shell. You could explicitly call a shell:

```
find -printf "%P\n"| sort | xargs -I '{}' bash -c 'echo $(uuid) {}'
```

---

Btw, I would use the following command:

```
find -exec bash -c 'echo "$(uuid) ${1#./}"' -- '{}' \;
```

without `xargs`.

Comment: Nicely done; but not only is  `-n 1` is superfluous, because `-I` implies line-by-line processing, `-n 1` would actually split by _any_ whitespace, whether line-interior or not. While `-L 1` does perform line-by-line processing, word-splitting is still applied to each line, whereas `-I` treats the entire line as a _single_ argument.

Answer (score 6):

[hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278715/45375) explains the problem well and his solution works well; this answer looks at **performance**.

The accepted answer is a tad slow, because it creates a `bash` process for every input line.

While **`xargs` is generally preferable to and faster than a shell-code loop, in this particular case the roles are reversed**, because shell functionality is needed in each iteration.

The following alternative solution uses a `while` loop to process the input lines, and, on my machine, is about *twice as fast* as the `xargs` solution.

```
find . -printf "%P\n" | sort | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$(uuid) $f"; done
```

- Note the use of `while` rather than `for`, because `for` cannot robustly parse command output (in short: filenames with embedded whitespace would break the command - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

<sup>If you're concerned about filenames with embedded newlines (very rare) and use *GNU* utilities, you could use NUL bytes as separators:</sup>

```
find . -printf "%P\0" | sort -z | while IFS= read -d '' -r f; do echo "$(uuid) $f"; done
```

**Update**: The ***fastest* approach** is to not use a shell loop at all, as evidenced by **[ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ's clever answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278775/45375)**.
See below for a portable version of his answer.

---

**Compatibility note:**

The OP's `find` command implies the use of *GNU* `find` (Linux), and uses features (`-printf`) that may not work on other platforms.

Here's a **portable version of [ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29278775/45375)** that uses only POSIX-compliant features of `find` (and `awk`).
Note, however, that `uuid` is not a POSIX utility; since Linux and BSD-like systems (including OSX) have a `uuidgen` utility, the command uses that instead:

```
 find . -exec printf '%s\t' {} \; -exec uuidgen \; | 
   awk -F '\t' '{ sub(/.+\//,"", $1); print $2, $1 }' | sort -k2
```

Answer (score 4):

<s>With a for loop:</s>

```
for i in $(find -printf "%P\n" | sort) ; do echo "$(uuid) $i";  done
```

Edit: another way to do this:

```
find -printf "%P\0" -exec uuid -v 4 \; | sort | awk -F'\0' '{ print $2 " " $1}'
```

this outputs the filename followed by the uuid (no subshell required) for letting the sort to happen, then swaps the two columns separated by null.

Comment: This also works and is a slightly easier version to read as well as not having the overhead of a new bash on every argument. If I could split the credit, I would. Thanks.

Comment: Using a shell loop in this instance is a good idea for performance reasons, but it's better to use a `while` loop, because `for` will break with filenames with embedded spaces, for instance - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: @mklement0 that's very true thanks; anyway I decided this one that's discarding the loop is better

Comment: Nicely done - that's even faster. As an aside: what platform are you (and the OP) on that you have a `uuid` utility? On BSD-like systems and Linux it's `uuidgen`. Interestingly, BSD `awk` interprets `-F'\0'` as `-F ''` (i.e., the _empty string_) and therefore splits the lines into individual characters (however, the `find` command as written wouldn't work with BSD `find` anyway).

Comment: @mklement0 it is this program http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/ packaged for fedora in my case; and GNU findutils 4.5.12

Comment: @mklement0 ...and on mine, uuid is in the same findutils package in Ubuntu. Interestingly the uuid utility creates time-based id's whereas uuidgen creates random-based id's (by default). This results in a strikingly different output when run in a loop - uuid creates sets of very similar ids, uuidgen creates more randomised values.

Comment: @adelphus: Thanks for that; let me add: _GNU_ `uuidgen` allows explicit control of what type to generate: `-r` for random-based, `-t` for time-based. _BSD_ `uuidgen`, by contrast, doesn't support this, and seemingly _invariably_ creates _random_-based ones.